# How to implement Undo, Redo and erase in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, draw

I am using this [**source code**](https://github.com/ww6015132/SilkySignature) and working well but here i am unable to implement undo, redo and erase functionality. i also create class for such functionality

```
private static class DrawOp {
        public final Path path = new Path();
        public Type type;
        public int color;
        public int stroke;

        public DrawOp() {
            //
        }

        public void reset() {
            this.path.reset();
        }

        public DrawOp(DrawOp op) {
            this.path.set(op.path);
            this.type = op.type;
            this.color = op.color;
            this.stroke = op.stroke;
        }

        public static enum Type {
            PAINT, ERASE;
        }
    }
```

For eraser

```
        mPaintEraser.set(mPaintColor);
        mPaintEraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPaintEraser.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 4, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

i try a  lot but not working please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

```
// My Drawing full class code

public class SignaturePad extends View {
    private static final int DOUBLE_CLICK_DELAY_MS = 200;
    private final SvgBuilder mSvgBuilder = new SvgBuilder();

    //Default attribute values

    private final int DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_MIN_WIDTH_PX = 3;
    private final int DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_MAX_WIDTH_PX = 7;
    private final int DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private final float DEFAULT_ATTR_VELOCITY_FILTER_WEIGHT = 0.9f;
    private final boolean DEFAULT_ATTR_CLEAR_ON_DOUBLE_CLICK = false;
    //View state
    private List<TimedPoint> mPoints;
    private boolean mIsEmpty;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mLastVelocity;
    private float mLastWidth;
    private RectF mDirtyRect;
    // Cache
    private List<TimedPoint> mPointsCache = new ArrayList<>();
    private ControlTimedPoints mControlTimedPointsCached = new ControlTimedPoints();
    private Bezier mBezierCached = new Bezier();
    //Configurable parameters
    private int mMinWidth;
    private int mMaxWidth;
    private float mVelocityFilterWeight;
    private OnSignedListener mOnSignedListener;
    private boolean mClearOnDoubleClick;
    //Click values
    private long mFirstClick;
    private int mCountClick;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap mSignatureBitmap = null;
    private Canvas mSignatureBitmapCanvas = null;

    //    private ArrayList<DrawOp> mDrawOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();
//    private DrawOp mCurrentOp = new DrawOp();

//    private ArrayList<DrawOp> mUndoneOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();
//    private final Canvas mLayerCanvas = new Canvas();

    public SignaturePad(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.SignaturePad,
                0, 0);

        //Configurable parameters
        try {
            mMinWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SignaturePad_penMinWidth, convertDpToPx(DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_MIN_WIDTH_PX));
            mMaxWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.SignaturePad_penMaxWidth, convertDpToPx(DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_MAX_WIDTH_PX));
            mPaint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.SignaturePad_penColor, DEFAULT_ATTR_PEN_COLOR));
            mVelocityFilterWeight = a.getFloat(R.styleable.SignaturePad_velocityFilterWeight, DEFAULT_ATTR_VELOCITY_FILTER_WEIGHT);
            mClearOnDoubleClick = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SignaturePad_clearOnDoubleClick, DEFAULT_ATTR_CLEAR_ON_DOUBLE_CLICK);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        //Fixed parameters
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        //Dirty rectangle to update only the changed portion of the view
        mDirtyRect = new RectF();

        clear();
    }

    public void setPenColorRes(int colorRes) {
        try {
            setPenColor(getResources().getColor(colorRes));
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ex) {
            setPenColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    }

    public void setPenColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setMinWidth(float minWidth) {
        mMinWidth = convertDpToPx(minWidth);
    }

    public void setMaxWidth(float maxWidth) {
        mMaxWidth = convertDpToPx(maxWidth);
    }

    public void setVelocityFilterWeight(float velocityFilterWeight) {
        mVelocityFilterWeight = velocityFilterWeight;
    }

    public void clear() {
        mSvgBuilder.clear();
        mPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        mLastVelocity = 0;
        mLastWidth = (mMinWidth + mMaxWidth) / 2;

        if (mSignatureBitmap != null) {
            mSignatureBitmap = null;
            ensureSignatureBitmap();
        }

        setIsEmpty(true);

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled())
            return false;

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//                mUndoneOps.clear();
//                mCurrentOp.path.moveTo(x, y);
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                mPoints.clear();
                if (isDoubleClick()) break;
                mLastTouchX = eventX;
                mLastTouchY = eventY;
                addPoint(getNewPoint(eventX, eventY));
                if (mOnSignedListener != null) mOnSignedListener.onStartSigning();

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//                for (int i = 0; i < event.getHistorySize(); i++) {
//                    mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(event.getHistoricalX(i), event.getHistoricalY(i));
//                }
//                mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                addPoint(getNewPoint(eventX, eventY));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                addPoint(getNewPoint(eventX, eventY));
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                setIsEmpty(false);
                break;
//            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
//                mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
//                mDrawOps.add(new DrawOp(mCurrentOp));
//                mCurrentOp.path.reset();
//                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }

        //invalidate();
        invalidate(
                (int) (mDirtyRect.left - mMaxWidth),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.top - mMaxWidth),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.right + mMaxWidth),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.bottom + mMaxWidth));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mSignatureBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mSignatureBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
        }

//        mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
//        for (DrawOp op : mDrawOps) {
//            drawOp(mLayerCanvas, op);
//        }
//        drawOp(mLayerCanvas, mCurrentOp);

    }

    public void setOnSignedListener(OnSignedListener listener) {
        mOnSignedListener = listener;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mIsEmpty;
    }

    public String getSignatureSvg() {
        int width = getTransparentSignatureBitmap().getWidth();
        int height = getTransparentSignatureBitmap().getHeight();
        return mSvgBuilder.build(width, height);
    }

    public Bitmap getSignatureBitmap() {
        Bitmap originalBitmap = getTransparentSignatureBitmap();
        Bitmap whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(whiteBgBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        return whiteBgBitmap;
    }

    public void setSignatureBitmap(final Bitmap signature) {
        // View was laid out...
        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
            clear();
            ensureSignatureBitmap();

            RectF tempSrc = new RectF();
            RectF tempDst = new RectF();

            int dWidth = signature.getWidth();
            int dHeight = signature.getHeight();
            int vWidth = getWidth();
            int vHeight = getHeight();

            // Generate the required transform.
            tempSrc.set(0, 0, dWidth, dHeight);
            tempDst.set(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight);

            Matrix drawMatrix = new Matrix();
            drawMatrix.setRectToRect(tempSrc, tempDst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mSignatureBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(signature, drawMatrix, null);
            setIsEmpty(false);
            invalidate();
        }
        // View not laid out yet e.g. called from onCreate(), onRestoreInstanceState()...
        else {
            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // Remove layout listener...
                    ViewTreeObserverCompat.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(getViewTreeObserver(), this);

                    // Signature bitmap...
                    setSignatureBitmap(signature);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param compressPercentage Hint to the compressor, 0-100 percent. 0 meaning compress for
     *                           small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some
     *                           formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the
     *                           quality setting
     */
    public Bitmap getCompressedSignatureBitmap(int compressPercentage) {

        if (compressPercentage < 0) {
            compressPercentage = 0;
        } else if (compressPercentage > 100) {
            compressPercentage = 100;
        }
        Bitmap originalBitmap = getTransparentSignatureBitmap();
        int originalWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();

        int targetWidth = originalWidth * compressPercentage / 100; // your arbitrary fixed limit
        int targetHeight = (int) (originalHeight * targetWidth / (double) originalWidth);

        Bitmap whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalWidth, originalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(whiteBgBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
        return whiteBgBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * @param deiredWidth Desired width of the bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getFixedSizeSignatureBitmap(int deiredWidth) {

        Bitmap originalBitmap = getTransparentSignatureBitmap();
        int originalWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();

        int targetWidth = deiredWidth; // your arbitrary fixed limit
        int targetHeight = (int) (originalHeight * targetWidth / (double) originalWidth);

        Bitmap whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalWidth, originalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(whiteBgBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
        return whiteBgBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * @param deiredWidth Desired width of the bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getFixedSizeSignatureBitmap(int deiredWidth, int desiredHeight) {

        Bitmap originalBitmap = getTransparentSignatureBitmap();
        int originalWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();

        int targetWidth = deiredWidth; // your arbitrary fixed limit
        int targetHeight = desiredHeight;

        Bitmap whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalWidth, originalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(whiteBgBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        whiteBgBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
        return whiteBgBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getTransparentSignatureBitmap() {
        ensureSignatureBitmap();
        return mSignatureBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getTransparentSignatureBitmap(boolean trimBlankSpace) {

        if (!trimBlankSpace) {
            return getTransparentSignatureBitmap();
        }

        ensureSignatureBitmap();

        int imgHeight = mSignatureBitmap.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = mSignatureBitmap.getWidth();

        int backgroundColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;

        int xMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                xMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                yMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                yMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        boolean foundPixel = false;

        // Find xMin
        for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
            boolean stop = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                if (mSignatureBitmap.getPixel(x, y) != backgroundColor) {
                    xMin = x;
                    stop = true;
                    foundPixel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Image is empty...
        if (!foundPixel)
            return null;

        // Find yMin
        for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
            boolean stop = false;
            for (int x = xMin; x < imgWidth; x++) {
                if (mSignatureBitmap.getPixel(x, y) != backgroundColor) {
                    yMin = y;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Find xMax
        for (int x = imgWidth - 1; x >= xMin; x--) {
            boolean stop = false;
            for (int y = yMin; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                if (mSignatureBitmap.getPixel(x, y) != backgroundColor) {
                    xMax = x;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Find yMax
        for (int y = imgHeight - 1; y >= yMin; y--) {
            boolean stop = false;
            for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++) {
                if (mSignatureBitmap.getPixel(x, y) != backgroundColor) {
                    yMax = y;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(mSignatureBitmap, xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
    }

    private boolean isDoubleClick() {
        if (mClearOnDoubleClick) {
            if (mFirstClick != 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - mFirstClick > DOUBLE_CLICK_DELAY_MS) {
                mCountClick = 0;
            }
            mCountClick++;
            if (mCountClick == 1) {
                mFirstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (mCountClick == 2) {
                long lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (lastClick - mFirstClick < DOUBLE_CLICK_DELAY_MS) {
                    this.clear();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private TimedPoint getNewPoint(float x, float y) {
        int mCacheSize = mPointsCache.size();
        TimedPoint timedPoint;
        if (mCacheSize == 0) {
            // Cache is empty, create a new point
            timedPoint = new TimedPoint();
        } else {
            // Get point from cache
            timedPoint = mPointsCache.remove(mCacheSize - 1);
        }

        return timedPoint.set(x, y);
    }

    private void recyclePoint(TimedPoint point) {
        mPointsCache.add(point);
    }

    private void addPoint(TimedPoint newPoint) {
        mPoints.add(newPoint);

        int pointsCount = mPoints.size();
        if (pointsCount > 3) {

            ControlTimedPoints tmp = calculateCurveControlPoints(mPoints.get(0), mPoints.get(1), mPoints.get(2));
            TimedPoint c2 = tmp.c2;
            recyclePoint(tmp.c1);

            tmp = calculateCurveControlPoints(mPoints.get(1), mPoints.get(2), mPoints.get(3));
            TimedPoint c3 = tmp.c1;
            recyclePoint(tmp.c2);

            Bezier curve = mBezierCached.set(mPoints.get(1), c2, c3, mPoints.get(2));

            TimedPoint startPoint = curve.startPoint;
            TimedPoint endPoint = curve.endPoint;

            float velocity = endPoint.velocityFrom(startPoint);
            velocity = Float.isNaN(velocity) ? 0.0f : velocity;

            velocity = mVelocityFilterWeight * velocity
                    + (1 - mVelocityFilterWeight) * mLastVelocity;

            // The new width is a function of the velocity. Higher velocities
            // correspond to thinner strokes.
            float newWidth = strokeWidth(velocity);

            // The Bezier's width starts out as last curve's final width, and
            // gradually changes to the stroke width just calculated. The new
            // width calculation is based on the velocity between the Bezier's
            // start and end mPoints.
            addBezier(curve, mLastWidth, newWidth);

            mLastVelocity = velocity;
            mLastWidth = newWidth;

            // Remove the first element from the list,
            // so that we always have no more than 4 mPoints in mPoints array.
            recyclePoint(mPoints.remove(0));

            recyclePoint(c2);
            recyclePoint(c3);

        } else if (pointsCount == 1) {
            // To reduce the initial lag make it work with 3 mPoints
            // by duplicating the first point
            TimedPoint firstPoint = mPoints.get(0);
            mPoints.add(getNewPoint(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y));
        }
    }

    private void addBezier(Bezier curve, float startWidth, float endWidth) {
        mSvgBuilder.append(curve, (startWidth + endWidth) / 2);
        ensureSignatureBitmap();
        float originalWidth = mPaint.getStrokeWidth();
        float widthDelta = endWidth - startWidth;
        float drawSteps = (float) Math.floor(curve.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < drawSteps; i++) {
            // Calculate the Bezier (x, y) coordinate for this step.
            float t = ((float) i) / drawSteps;
            float tt = t * t;
            float ttt = tt * t;
            float u = 1 - t;
            float uu = u * u;
            float uuu = uu * u;

            float x = uuu * curve.startPoint.x;
            x += 3 * uu * t * curve.control1.x;
            x += 3 * u * tt * curve.control2.x;
            x += ttt * curve.endPoint.x;

            float y = uuu * curve.startPoint.y;
            y += 3 * uu * t * curve.control1.y;
            y += 3 * u * tt * curve.control2.y;
            y += ttt * curve.endPoint.y;

            // Set the incremental stroke width and draw.
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(startWidth + ttt * widthDelta);
            mSignatureBitmapCanvas.drawPoint(x, y, mPaint);
            expandDirtyRect(x, y);
        }

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(originalWidth);
    }

    private ControlTimedPoints calculateCurveControlPoints(TimedPoint s1, TimedPoint s2, TimedPoint s3) {
        float dx1 = s1.x - s2.x;
        float dy1 = s1.y - s2.y;
        float dx2 = s2.x - s3.x;
        float dy2 = s2.y - s3.y;

        float m1X = (s1.x + s2.x) / 2.0f;
        float m1Y = (s1.y + s2.y) / 2.0f;
        float m2X = (s2.x + s3.x) / 2.0f;
        float m2Y = (s2.y + s3.y) / 2.0f;

        float l1 = (float) Math.sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1);
        float l2 = (float) Math.sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2);

        float dxm = (m1X - m2X);
        float dym = (m1Y - m2Y);
        float k = l2 / (l1 + l2);
        if (Float.isNaN(k)) k = 0.0f;
        float cmX = m2X + dxm * k;
        float cmY = m2Y + dym * k;

        float tx = s2.x - cmX;
        float ty = s2.y - cmY;

        return mControlTimedPointsCached.set(getNewPoint(m1X + tx, m1Y + ty), getNewPoint(m2X + tx, m2Y + ty));
    }

    private float strokeWidth(float velocity) {
        return Math.max(mMaxWidth / (velocity + 1), mMinWidth);
    }

    /**
     * Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
     * mPoints.
     *
     * @param historicalX the previous x coordinate.
     * @param historicalY the previous y coordinate.
     */
    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < mDirtyRect.left) {
            mDirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > mDirtyRect.right) {
            mDirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < mDirtyRect.top) {
            mDirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > mDirtyRect.bottom) {
            mDirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the dirty region when the motion event occurs.
     *
     * @param eventX the event x coordinate.
     * @param eventY the event y coordinate.
     */
    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

        // The mLastTouchX and mLastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN motion event occurred.
        mDirtyRect.left = Math.min(mLastTouchX, eventX);
        mDirtyRect.right = Math.max(mLastTouchX, eventX);
        mDirtyRect.top = Math.min(mLastTouchY, eventY);
        mDirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(mLastTouchY, eventY);
    }

    private void setIsEmpty(boolean newValue) {
        mIsEmpty = newValue;
        if (mOnSignedListener != null) {
            if (mIsEmpty) {
                mOnSignedListener.onClear();
            } else {
                mOnSignedListener.onSigned();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ensureSignatureBitmap() {
        if (mSignatureBitmap == null) {
            mSignatureBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mSignatureBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mSignatureBitmap);
        }
    }

    private int convertDpToPx(float dp) {
        return Math.round(getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * dp);
    }

//    public void setDrawingColor(int color) {
//        mCurrentOp.reset();
//        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
//        mCurrentOp.color = color;
//    }
//
//    public void setDrawingStroke(int stroke) {
//        mCurrentOp.reset();
//        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
//        mCurrentOp.stroke = stroke;
//    }
//
//    public void enableEraser() {
//        mCurrentOp.reset();
//        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.ERASE;
//    }
//
//    public void clearDrawing() {
//        mDrawOps.clear();
//        mUndoneOps.clear();
//        mCurrentOp.reset();
//        invalidate();
//    }
//
//    public void undoOperation() {
//        if (mDrawOps.size() > 0) {
//            DrawOp last = mDrawOps.remove(mDrawOps.size() - 1);
//            mUndoneOps.add(last);
//            invalidate();
//        }
//    }
//
//    public void redoOperation() {
//        if (mUndoneOps.size() > 0) {
//            DrawOp redo = mUndoneOps.remove(mUndoneOps.size() - 1);
//            mDrawOps.add(redo);
//            invalidate();
//        }
//    }
//
//    private void drawOp(Canvas canvas, DrawOp op) {
//        if (op.path.isEmpty()) {
//            return;
//        }
//        final Paint paint;
//        if (op.type == DrawOp.Type.PAINT) {
//            paint = mPaint;
//            paint.setColor(op.color);
//            paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
//        } else {
//            paint = mPaint;
//            paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
//        }
//        mLayerCanvas.drawPath(op.path, paint);
//    }

    public interface OnSignedListener {
        void onStartSigning();

        void onSigned();

        void onClear();
    }

//    private static class DrawOp {
//        public final Path path = new Path();
//        public Type type;
//        public int color;
//        public int stroke;
//
//        public DrawOp() {
//            //
//        }
//
//        public DrawOp(DrawOp op) {
//            this.path.set(op.path);
//            this.type = op.type;
//            this.color = op.color;
//            this.stroke = op.stroke;
//        }
//
//        public void reset() {
//            this.path.reset();
//        }
//
//        public static enum Type {
//            PAINT, ERASE;
//        }
//    }

}
```

i uses code for undo and redo but here some problem after undo tiny line still show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `canvas` holds a `bitmap`, and any draw operation you perform affects the pixels of the underlying bitmap. So there is no such thing as "out of the box" undo or redo.

In order to implement Undo or Redo feature, you need to make your draw operations as a command. And you need to store all your draw operations in a list. For instance, let's say you do the following:

1. Clear canvas
2. Draw background color
3. Draw Path from A to B
4. Draw Circle with radius 50f with center (100,100)
5. Draw Path from B to C

All these operations have to saved in your list in some format. Now when you

1. tap on UNDO, you need to do operations [0,1,2,3]
2. tap on UNDO again, you need to do operations [0,1,2]
3. tap on REDO, you need to do [0,1,2,3]
4. tap on REDO again, you need to do [0,1,2,3,4]

I hope you get the idea, you need to encapsulate the drawing operations, store them in an array and perform these operations.

---

**How to perform ERASE?**

Again there is no erase operation, Erasing is just drawing again on the canvas and this means you need to set the color of the paint to match the background color. So if your canvas is in RED color, and you are drawing using WHITE color, erasing means drawing with RED color.

So what if the background is not a simple color, but an image? In this case you need to have 2 canvas. One will be your original canvas (canvas A with bitmap A) with the actual image bitmap, the other one is the temporary canvas (canvas B with bitmap B). So to erase, you have to do something like below:

1. Draw your draw operations like Path, circle in Canvas B.
2. Then take the Bitmap B and draw that on Canvas A. (using `canvas.drawBitmap()`)
3. Now when you want to erase, you need to draw (with paint xfermode Clear) on canvas B. This will make the already drawn pixels to be transparent.
4. Repeat step 2.

Comment: Yes exactly but i try a lot and unable to embed in project please i provided source code in question please do it for me thanks. :)